# Angular mdDialog controller code fails when minified

Tags: angularjs, minify, mddialog

I successfully added a custom template `mdDialog` to request a name and a boolean (from a checkbox) dialog that pops up on click of an element.

However, while it works great in development, it fails on production, as the build process minifies the js code. I found many examples in SO about this issue but none of them that highlights how to fix something in my case, in most cases it is a resolve or something that is easy to grasp. My code is:

```
function DialogController ( $scope, $mdDialog, gsheet, name ) {
  $scope.name = name;
  $scope.gsheet = gsheet;

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $mdDialog.cancel ();
  };

  $scope.create = function ( name, gsheet ) {
    $mdDialog.hide ( { 'name': name, 'createSheet': gsheet ? gsheet : false } );
  };
}

function openNewDataSourceDialog ( ev ) {
  if ( !$rootScope.driveAuth ) {
    $rootScope.$emit ( 'requestMoreAuth' );
  }
  else {

    var confirm = $mdDialog.prompt ( {
      templateUrl: "app/main/data-sources/data-sources-dialog.tmpl.html",
      parent: angular.element ( document.body ),
      clickOutsideToClose: true,
      targetEvent: ev,
      controller: DialogController,
      fullscreen: false,
      scope: $scope,
      preserveScope: true,
      locals: {
        name: "",
        gsheet: true
      }
    } );

    $mdDialog.show ( confirm ).then ( function ( result ) {
      //create something...
    }, function () {
      //dont create anything...
    } );
  }
};
```

Any ideas on what is breaking the minification here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It mostly happen when you minify also `$mdDialog` name. Add [Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) for it.

In your case:

```
      var confirm = $mdDialog.prompt ( {
      templateUrl: "app/main/data-sources/data-sources-dialog.tmpl.html",
      parent: angular.element ( document.body ),
      clickOutsideToClose: true,
      targetEvent: ev,
      controller: ['$scope', '$mdDialog', 'gsheet', 'name', 
           function ($scope, $mdDialog, gsheet, name) { /* ... */}],
      fullscreen: false,
      scope: $scope,
      preserveScope: true,
      locals: {
        name: "",
        gsheet: true
      }
    } );
```

Or:

```
//...
controller: ['$scope', '$mdDialog', 'gsheet', 'name', DialogController],
//...
```

Comment: Thanks, will try. Thanks for the edits too, make sense. :)

Comment: @geodeath I had same issue before 2 years :)

Comment: Edited the controller creation with your edit and it works but it is a nice idea to do it in the attribute instead. Keeps the code cleaner i guess. :) thanks!